# [Javascript]: Sprite is offset

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, sprite, 2d-games

So I was coding some game (or what I call game) in JavaScript. And basically, you're supposed to click a place on the canvas and the player will be drawn there. But when I clicked the sprite was offset by some amount (I don't exactly know how much) to the point on the mouse. How can I get it so that the sprite will be draw exactly on the point of the mouse?

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmSKz.jpg

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoved, false);
canvas.addEventListener('click', drawPlayerPos, false);

var spriteSheet = new Image();
spriteSheet.src = 'spritesheet.png';
spriteSheet.addEventListener('load', init, false);

var gameWidth = canvas.width;
var gameHeight = canvas.height;

function init()
{
    drawPlayerPos();
}


var mouseX;
var mouseY;

function mouseMoved(e)
{
    mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    document.getElementById('mouseCoors').innerHTML = 'X: ' + mouseX + ' Y: ' + mouseY;
}

function drawPlayerPos()
{
    var srcX = 1;
    var srcY = 1;
    var drawX = mouseX;
    var drawY = mouseY;
    var width = 15;
    var height = 15;
    ctx.drawImage(spriteSheet,srcX,srcY,width,height,drawX,drawY,width,height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sprite is 15x15, you want `srcX` and `srcY` to be 0, not 1. And note that your code draws the top left corner of the sprite at the mouse point; if you want it to be centered you need to do:

```
drawX = mouseX - width / 2;
drawY = mouseY - height / 2;
```